# SQL Server table design to define WHERE condition

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing Stored procedure which has lots of hard-coding with IF conditions. The procedure checks the values of following input fields and displays relevant message: The fields are:

•   BrandId
•   ProductId
•   SchemeId
•   RegionId

The existing Message table:

**MsgId   MsgText**

1         AAAA
2         BBBB
3         CCCC
4         MMMM

Existing stored proc. pseudo code:

```
IF(BrandId in (5,10))
    IF(@ProductId in (5))
        SELECT ‘BBBB’ as  MsgText
    END IF
END IF

IF(SchemeId in (1,5,10))
    SELECT ‘AAAA’ as  MsgText

IF(SchemeId =2 AND @RegionId=4)
    SELECT ‘BBBB’ as  MsgText

IF (@RegionId=6)
    SELECT ‘MMMM’ as  MsgText
```

In order to remove hard-coding and re-writing the procedure cleanly from scratch, I want to  design new tables which will store "MsgId"s against a BrandId/ProdId/PlanId/SchemeId value or against a combination of these fields (e.g SchemeId =2 AND RegionId=4).With this kind of design I can directly fetch the relevant MsgId against a specific field   or combination of fields.

Could anybody suggest table designs to meet the requirement?

Comment: Does the procedure stop when an `if` statement returns a result, or is it putting these messages in a temp table, or returning multiple result sets?

Comment: You are correct. The procedure putting the messages in a temp table and finally selects the records from the temp table.

Comment: @SqlZim,  you have any thoughts on the table design and data?

Comment: I don't suggestions yet, it's a tough situation without knowing the relationships those Ids have to one another. Are there more rules you can observe about this? e.g. messages for products always also check brand.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The fields should be mapped with a message id with any combination. In few cases a single field is mapped against a messageId and in most of the cases a message is mapped agAinst a combination of fields. I can design multiple tables  if required. Also, could you think of a design if messages for products always also check brand? I think table designs with that assumption also help.

Comment: Are there a set number of SchemeIds and RegionIds or does that change often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your responses to the comments, this might work out.

```sql
create table dbo.[Messages] (
    MessageId int not null
  , MessageText nvarchar(1024) not null
  , constraint pk_Messages primary key clustered (MessageId)
  );

insert into dbo.[Messages] (MessageId,MessageText) values
    (1,'AAAA')
  , (2,'BBBB')
  , (13,'MMMM');

create table dbo.Messages_BrandProduct (
    BrandId int not null
  , ProductId int not null
  , MessageId int not null
  , constraint pk_Messages_BrandProduct primary key clustered 
    (BrandId, ProductId, MessageId)
  );

insert into dbo.Messages_BrandProduct (BrandId, ProductId, MessageId) values
    (5,5,2)
   ,(10,5,2);

create table dbo.Messages_SchemeRegion (
    SchemeId int not null
  , RegionId int not null
  , MessageId int not null
  , constraint pk_Messages_SchemeRegion primary key clustered 
    (SchemeId, RegionId, MessageId)
  );

insert into dbo.Messages_SchemeRegion (SchemeId, RegionId, MessageId) 
  select SchemeId =  1, RegionId    , MessageId =  1 from dbo.Regions
    union all                                      
  select SchemeId =  5, RegionId    , MessageId =  1 from dbo.Regions
    union all                                      
  select SchemeId = 10, RegionId    , MessageId =  1 from dbo.Regions
    union all                                      
  select SchemeId =  2, RegionId = 4, MessageId =  2
    union all
  select SchemeId     , RegionId = 6, MessageId = 13 from dbo.Schemes;
```

In your procedure you could pull the messages like this:

```
  select MessageId 
    from dbo.Messages_BrandProduct mbp 
      inner join dbo.[Messages] m on mbp.MessageId=m.MessageId
    where mbp.BrandId = @BrandId and mbp.ProductId = @ProductId
  union -- union all if you don't need to deduplicate messages
  select MessageId 
    from dbo.Messages_SchemeRegion msr
      inner join dbo.[Messages] m on msr.MessageId=m.MessageId
    where msr.SchemeId = @SchemeId and msr.RegionId = @RegionId;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will check the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IDs](
[BrandID] [int] NOT NULL,
[ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
[SchemeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[RegionID] [int] NOT NULL,
[MsgID] [int] NOT NULL
```

)

You can adjust the table and column names as needed. Cheers.

Comment: This will not work. How I would store data if I want to  fetch MsgId "4" for RegionId "6" and  MsgId "2" for BrandId in (5,10) and ProductId 5 as shown in existing procedure logic

Comment: Are you familiar with database normalization?(https://www.udemy.com/blog/normalization-in-database-with-example/) The complexity that you are encountering is likely the result of table design that does not adhere to 3rd normal form. Check this out. It will take your db skills to a new level.